# How do you bind the Fn key to the Ctrl function?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My laptop has a Fn key right where I always expect the Ctrl key to be.  I would like to make the Fn key behave just like the Ctrl key so I stop trying to Fn+C and Fn+V and Fn+Tab instead of Ctrl+C Ctrl+V and Ctrl+Tab.

Is this possible?

Note: I don't care if I am unable to use the Fn key as an actual function key.  I never use it for that purpose anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually managed by the BIOS itself. Depending on your laptop's brand/make, you can enter the BIOS and choose whether to use the Fn/Control or Control/Fn key bindings.

Give this a try and please update your question just in case that your laptop's BIOS isn't having the proper switch for swapping the keys.

Good luck!